# Is it possible to manually scroll a gallery based on a touch event captured elsewhere on the screen

Tags: java, android, gallery

In my Android app I have a gallery which contains some TextViews. I realized that some users don't understand that they can scroll that gallery although the previous and next TextViews are partially visible. So I put an ImageView with a horizontal arrow under the gallery.
Now the users try to drag the arrow. Is it possible to redirect the touch event from the ImageView to the gallery so that dragging it would scroll the gallery?

Thanks in advance,
Fri

Comment: I would reword this as "Is it possible to manually scroll a gallery based on a touch event captured elsewhere on the screen".

Comment: You are right, this one is more expressive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing (if you don't mind scrolling one item at a time) is to detect the direction of the touch event on the arrow and then dispatchSetSelected(boolean selected) on the gallery... I believe that will work. after the user does that once, they will probably intuit that they can then just drag the gallery.  Of course if you want to measure the touch event speed and do the calculation for how far to scroll based on that, you can do that too... but that seems like a lot of unnecessary trouble.